# How to prevent a custom button from disappearing when entering fullscreen mode in @react-google-maps/api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have created a custom button on a Google Map using the @react-google-maps/api library. However, when I enter fullscreen mode, the button disappears. I have tried adjusting the z-index and other styling properties using the browser console, but I have not been successful in preventing the button from disappearing.

I have created a code sandbox with a simplified version of my code to demonstrate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-chihiro-ns1vv?file=/src/LoadMap.jsx

To reproduce the issue, please click on the "open in a new window" button to enter fullscreen mode.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how to prevent the custom button from disappearing when entering fullscreen mode. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With MapControl component.

```
    <MapControl position={google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER}>
  <div>That was easy</div>
</MapControl>
```

https://gist.github.com/jgimbel/6a36d60e28aaf453d0093ddc47f36533

Answer (score 0):

fullscreen mode creates inside it  element. You should add your button after it creates, in React you can do it with ReactDOM.createPortal. Here you should add your btn: `document.getElementById('your-map-id').getElementsByTagName('div')[0]`